# Como publicar um WebService usando o Visual Studio C#?

Tags: c#, web-service, visual-studio-2015

Estou tentando publicar um Webservice com o Visual Studio mas a conexão está falhando. Alguém consegue ajudar-me a conectar nesse projeto?

Eis a mensagem de erro de quando eu tento publicar:

> Publishing folder /...
>   2>Unable to add 'Web.config' to the Web site.  Unable to add file 'Web.config'.  Acces denied..
>   2>Unable to add 'WebService1.asmx' to the Web site.  Unable to add file 'WebService1.asmx'. Acces denied.
>   2>Unable to add folder 'bin' to the Web site.  Cannot create folder 'bin'.   Acces denied.
>   2>Publish failed. Target file:///C:/inetpub/wwwroot/meuWebservice.
>   2>
>   ========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
>   ========== Publish: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========

O que estou fazendo de errado?

Comment: Welcome to StackoverflowPT, please translate your question into Portuguese.

Comment: Izabel, traduzi sua questão para português. Espero não ter me perdido na tradução. E também será muito mais útil para a comunidade lusófona perguntas em português

Comment: tente executar o vs como administrador

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Isso ocorre quando você não possui permissão para publicar no diretório de raiz de aplicativo (wwwroot). Tente executar o Visual Studio como administrador.

Se o mesmo não funcionar, você vai precisar dar permissão de escrita no diretório do IIS que você esta publicando. Abra o diretório, vá em **Propriedades** > **Segurança** > **Editar** > Dê a permissão desejada, mais detalhes:

https://technet.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/cc754344(v=ws.11).aspx

Ainda outra solução seria publicar em outro local onde você tenha permissão. Lembre-se de trocar o mapeamento do caminho físico da publicação no IIS para essa pasta.

Comment: Obrigada !! Funcionou!!